# Como retornar 3 elementos proximos de valor em uma lista em PYTHON?

Tags: python, lista

Estou estudando um exemplo e gostaria de entender como faço para pegar **3 elementos proximos** de um valor dentro de uma lista.

```py
Codigo:

def closest(lst, K): 
      
    return lst[min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: abs(lst[i]-K))] 
      
lst = [0.1301, 0.1320, 0.1338, 0.1357, 0.1376, 0.1395, 0.1413] 

K = 0.1352

print(closest(lst, K))
```

RESULTADO: 0.1357

Oque eu gostaria de entender é como edito o codigo pra conseguir receber 0.1320, 0.1338 e 0.1357 ( do menor para o maior ) como resultado.Estou tentando aprender python e estou com dificuldades para entender um pouco a linguagem e a logica. Agradeço desde já aos que puderem me auxiliar no meu estudo

Answer (score -3):

```
K = 0.1352
prox_vals = set(lst[:3])
for valor in lst[3:]:
    if abs(valor - K) < max(prox_vals, key=lambda x: abs(x - K)):
        prox_vals.remove(max(prox_vals, key=lambda x: abs(x - K)))
        prox_vals.add(valor)
print(prox_vals)
```

Geralmente em Python, usando menos linhas não significa que o códico é mais rápido. As vezes é melhor prioritizar que é mais legível

Comment: no seu codigo ele retorna os 3 primeiros elementos da lista independente do valor do "k", se "k" tivesse o valor de 0.1390 eu gostaria que me fosse retornado 0.1357, 0,1376 e 0.1395. Se k for maior que 0.1395 entao retornaria o proximo numero maior que k (0.1413) e os dois ultimos elementos. Oque preciso é cercar o valor da variavel, pegando sempre entre esses elementos proximos de k na lista oque não consigo e estou com dificuldades é entender um jeito pra passar essa logica pra python e que ela seja funcional